# How to make a word document readonly in runtime after opening without closing it before

Tags: vba, ms-word, readonly, read-write, readonly-attribute

Is it possible to make a word document ReadOnly in runtime after it has been opened in ReadWrite mode without closing it before?

Here is an example what I try to do:

```
Sub ProcessWordDoc()
Dim WordApp As New Word.Application
Dim Doc As Word.Document

WordApp.Visible = True

Set Doc = WordApp.Documents.Open(Filename:="C:\myWordTemplate.docx", ReadOnly:=False)

With Doc
    .Unprotect
    
    .FormFields("Firstname").Result = Me.Firstname
    .FormFields("Lastname").Result = Me.Lastname
    
    .Protect wdAllowOnlyReading
End With

' Make Doc ReadOnly after the document has been processed.
' Somthing like, but it does not work, since the ReadOnly property is read-only ;-)
Doc.ReadOnly = True

End Sub
```

So in a nutshell: is it possible to switch the mode of a word document via VBA from ReadWrite to ReadOnly?

Thanks for an help.

Comment: I doubt you can change the Read-Only state without saving and re-opening. (Not tried though so could be wrong) Are you trying to prevent the document from being saved with the form data in it? Because you can prevent the save action, or clear the form before the save action.

Comment: Why are you using a document for this rather than a template? https://www.addbalance.com/usersguide/templates.htm Also, you may want to look into Mapped Content Controls in the template. https://addbalance.com/word/MappedControls.htm#PageStart

Comment: @NickSlash Ok, that is what I was afread of. Thanks

Comment: @CharlesKenyon I could you a dotx file, but the problem/question remains. It seams that it is not possible to switch between ReadOnly an ReadWrite mode once the document is opened. Thanks for the hints.

Comment: Since you're apparently only populating/updating formfields, why are you even unprotecting the document? Quite unnecessary. And why, having unprotected it, aren't you re-applying 'filling in forms' protection?

Answer (score 0):

Expanding on my comment/alternative idea.

This will (should) create a new document from your template file, protect it after inserting the data and then "save" the document so it can be closed without being prompted to save it, so no new document is saved and your template is never edited.

```
Sub Main()
Dim WordApp As New Word.Application
Dim Doc As Word.Document

WordApp.Visible = True

Set Doc = WordApp.Documents.Add(Template:="C:\myWordTemplate.docx")

With Doc
    .Unprotect
    .FormFields("Firstname").Result = Me.Firstname
    .FormFields("Lastname").Result = Me.Lastname
    .Protect wdAllowOnlyReading
    '.Saved = True ' not desired
End With

End Sub
```

**Update**

I'm using Office 2016, so might not be the case for you. Using Word VBA I can open a document (with form fields and has `wdAllowOnlyReading` set) in Read-Only mode:

```
Dim Doc As Document: Set Document = Word.Documents.Open(FileName:"example.doc", ReadOnly:=True)
```

I am still able to use VBA to unprotect, modify form fields and re-protect this document even though it is read only. So there should be no need to open in `ReadWrite` and then change to `ReadOnly`.

Still, `Add(ing)` your template document instead of `Open(ing)` it seems like a better option to stop it from being modified.

Comment: This is a workaround, which is unfortunately not applicable if the user wants to decide if the document gets saved or not.

Comment: @Johin The example doesn't stop the user from saving it, only stops the user from being prompted to save it when they close the document. Removing the `.Saved = True` will stop this. Since you only showed the problem, and not the goal its hard to give possible solutions.